# Is there an event in Breezejs that is fired when an entity is added or deleted?

Tags: breeze

I have looked around for an answer to this, but I have come up dry so far.  What I would like to do is have an event handler in a specific view model that listens to Breeze for entities being added or deleted so the view model can take appropriate action on the array it is managing.  Does such an event exist?

I have a Jobs view model for my Jobs view that contains, among other properties, a ko.observableArray of Job entities, and a NewJob view model for my NewJob view.  Both view models share the same data service.  I would like to simply use the DataService from the NewJob view model to insert a new Job entity in to Breeze, and then have the Jobs view model simply subscribed to an event so it would know to add the new Job into it's Jobs array.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Breeze EntityManager has an [entityChanged event](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html) that may be used like so:

```
var em = new EntityManager( {serviceName: "api/NorthwindIBModel" });
em.entityChanged.subscribe(function(changeArgs) {
    // This code will be executed any time any entity within the entityManager is added, 
    // modified, deleted or detached for any reason. 
    var action = changeArgs.entityAction;
    var entity = changeArgs.entity;
    // .. do something to this entity when it is changed.
});
```

Comment: Performancewise woudn't it be better to have separate events instead of having subscriber to check for entityAction?

Comment: Problem with that is that many common use cases require the handling of multiple different actions with the same code path. i.e. tracking changes means tracking adds/mods and deletes but not detaches and this code would be more difficult to author separate events for each action. ... And so far we have never seen a significant perf impact in any of our large breeze apps, some of which are working with many thousands of entities in the cache at the same time.